# Not recieving push notification in IOS in a Xamarin Forms Application using Notification Hub

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

We are trying to implement Push Notification in a Xamarin Forms Application using Azure Notification Hub. We have configured properly in Azure Notification Hub, and we are receiving notifications in Android and Windows. But in IOS we are not receiving any notification.

We have done the following for iOS:

1. We got required distribution provisioning profile and p12 file from Microsoft team with “push notification” capability.
2. We configured notifications in azure mobile app and notification is successfully sending from azure to APNS.
3. At client mobile app, RegisteredForRemoteNotifications method is getting hit and no errors in device registration.
4. But, DidReceiveRemoteNotification is not hitting.

It will be of great help if someone can suggest in understanding what is going wrong here. We followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push#update-the-server-project-to-send-push-notifications) . Thanks for the help in advance.

[Service Bus Explorer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK9df.png)

Comment: App delegate code please, need to see what your doing with the device token, thanks.

Comment: In FinishedLaunching method
 var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
     UIUserNotificationType.Alert
     | UIUserNotificationType.Badge
     | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
     new NSSet());

 UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
 UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

Comment: I meant more specifically the method where you subscribe to the notification hub itself with your device token.

Comment: public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application,
     NSData deviceToken)
 {
     const string templateBodyAPNS = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"$(messageParam)\"}}";

     JObject templates = new JObject();
     templates["genericMessage"] = new JObject
         {
           {"body", templateBodyAPNS}
         };

     
     Push push = TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.GetPush();
     push.RegisterAsync(deviceToken, templates);
 }

Comment: That seems fairly straight forward, looks exactly like the example code on their xamarin dev page for the notification hub, If the code is identical to theirs then I would suggest downloading the service bus explorer application and do some tests against your notification hub to see if theres any errors coming back regarding the certificates, or the json template etc.

Comment: +1 to what @Digitalsa1nt said. Also, take a look at [Azure Notification Hubs - Diagnosis guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer)

Comment: We tried Service Bus Explorer Application but after connecting using  the connection Strings we couldn't see any Notification Hub. Though using the same connection strings we are sending notifications to Windows and Android. @Digitalsa1nt Please find the Service Bus Explorer Screenshot